# Separate nomenclatures for different chapters

Tags: subdividing, nomenclature

How can I have different nomenclatures for different chapters? I use Chapterbib for the reference. However I could not find any thing for nomenclature.

```
%-----------------    
 \documentclass[12pt]{report}

 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}%makes reference as a section (not a chapter)
 \usepackage{chapterbib}% makes possible to have references at the end of each chapter
 \usepackage{hyperref}%heperlinks references
 \usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
 \usepackage{framed}      % Framing content
 \usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}     % Nomenclature package [intoc] in table of content
 \makenomenclature
 \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items

 \begin{document}

 \include{chapter1}
 \include{chapter2}
 \end{document}


%---------------------------
\chapterfirst chapter}
this is for a reference \citep{Biot1956a}

$F=ma$
\nomenclature{$m$}{Mass}%
\bibliographystyle{model2-names}
\bibliography{bib}
\printnomenclature

%---------------------------
\chapter{second chapter}
this is for a reference \citep{Biot1956b}

$F=ma$
\nomenclature{$F$}{Force}%
\bibliographystyle{model2-names}
\bibliography{bib}
\printnomenclature


  %-------------


  @article{Biot1956b,
     author = {Biot, Maurice A.},
      doi = {10.1063/1.1722402},
     journal = {Journal of Applied Physics},
     number = {5},
       pages = {459},
     title = {{Theory of Deformation of a Porous Viscoelastic Anisotropic Solid}},
      volume = {27},
        year = {1956}
       }
       @article{Biot1956a,
       author = {Biot, Maurice A.},
     journal = {Journal of Applied Mechanics},
     pages = {91--96},
      title = {{General Soloutions of the Equations of Elasticity and Consolidation for            a Porous Material}},
      volume = {78},
      year = {1956}
       }
```

Comment: Please state more precisely: what do you mean by nomenclature?

Comment: Christian, Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: John, I will come back later on, but at the moment, I have no time, there is an evening class waiting for me to be taught in mathematics

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence Meoow ;-)